# Java facebook api 0AuthException when using acces token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to create a java program implementing facebook restfb sdk.
I have initialised my fbclient the following way.

```
FacebookClient fbclient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accesToken,Version.LATEST);
```

When trying to load ex.1, everything is fine. But, since i dont want to load thousands of posts, when i try ex.2, it gives me 0authexception. Although, if i use the facebook graph api explorer, it has no problem with the limit function.
Does anyone know what i might be doing wrong here?

ex,1

```
Connection<Post> postFeed = fbclient.fetchConnection(pageID + "/feed", Post.class);
```

e,2

```
Connection<Post> postFeed = fbclient.fetchConnection(pageID + "/feed?&limit=5", Post.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restfb sdk uses a different style to pass parameters. By reading further in the documentation, i accidentally encountered it.
Here's what fixes it.

```
Connection<Post> postFeed = fbclient.fetchConnection(pageID + "/feed", Post.class,Parameter.with("limit", 5));
```